# I need to get value from async lambda RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, lambda, rabbitmq

i need to return message from rabbitmq, like this [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html), but i don't know how i can return this message for continue development.
When i want to return this value i see "*variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final return*"

This is my code:

```
public Message receiveMessage() throws IOException, TimeoutException {

    Message result;

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    factory.setPort(rabbitMQContainer.getMappedPort(5672));
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages...");

    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {

        String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Message tempMessage = objectMapper.readValue(message, Message.class);

        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + tempMessage.toString() + "'");

        result = tempMessage;

        return tempMessage;

    };

    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show the code, you are probably trying to assign a variable outside the lambda inside the lambda

Comment: `result = tempMessage;` You can't assign a value to a variable that is declared outside the lambda inside it.

Comment: @123 How i can do it, if i only need to get this message from rabbit?

Comment: You would process the message in the callback.